# Arrange numbers to 3x3 square with concentric (Addition and Difference)

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

2 Similar questions:

### I. Difference

[image]

Arrange numbers 1 to 8 to replace the letters so:
A = abs (B – D)
C = abs (B – E)
F = abs (D – G)
H = abs (E – G)
To eliminate duplicates by rotation and reflection, let’s set the rules: A > C, A > F, A > H and F > C 
There are 2 solutions

### II. Addition

[image]
Arrange numbers 1 to 8 to replace the letters so:
A = B + D
C = B + E
F = D + G
H = E + G
To eliminate duplicates by rotation and reflection, let’s set the rules: A > C, A > F, A > H and F > C.
There is just 1 solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SUBTRACTION**

> [image]
>
>
>  A=7
>  B=1
>  C=4
>  D=8
>  E=5
>  F=6
>  G=2
>  H=3
>  A>C
>  A>F
>  A>H
>  F>C
>
>  **METHOD**
>
>  I tried to get the higher values inside the result box. I chose 7 out of 7 and 8. And then, got the following things working -
>
>  8-1 = 7
>  8-2 = 6(Next big number)
>  5-1 = 4(Next big number)
>  5-2 = 3(Final big number)

**ADDITION**

> [image]
>
>
>  A=8
>  B=2
>  C=5
>  D=6
>  E=3
>  F=7
>  G=1
>  H=4
>  A>C
>  A>F
>  A>H
>  F>C
>
>  **METHOD**
>
>  For addition, I tried getting the bigger numbers in the result box.
>
>  6+2 = 8(Biggest)
>  6+1 = 7(Next biggest)
>  3+2 = 5(Next biggest)
>  3+1 = 4(Final)

Comment: how do you solve it?

Comment: I will add the explaination on the method I used. Give me some time to figure out the other one(if I can)

Answer (score 5):

## Difference 1

> ```
>  5 8 2
>  3 - 6
>  4 7 1
> ```

Reasoning:

> 8 must go on a white square. 7 on an adjacent white is quickly dismissed. 1 must go on a blue square, otherwise we need another 7, and it can't be next to 8.

## Difference 2

> ```
>  7 1 4
>  8 - 5
>  6 2 3
> ```

Reasoning:

> 4 cannot go opposite 8, as 6 must be in a corner, which gives a 4-2 arrangement. And 4 cannot be adjacent to 8, and so must be in an opposite corner. 7 in the other opposite corner causes problems with placement of the 1.

## Addition

> ```
>  8 2 5
>  6 + 3
>  7 1 4
> ```

Reasoning:

> We know A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H=36, and that A+C+F+H=2(B+D+E+G), so that B+D+E+G=12. There are only two ways to do this: 1236, 1245. In the second case 1 and 4 must be opposite, but 1+5=2+4. In the first 1 and 2 must be opposite, and 1+3$\ne$1+6$\ne$2+3$\ne$2+6.